# How do you know whether the result of "onLeScan" is the device you are looking for?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

So I have a known BLE device that I want to connect to and interact with.

However my query is when results are being returned in the method from this reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html how can you check that the device returned in the callback is the one you want to interface with?

Sorry no code examples as I am on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Mac Address：`BluetoothDevice.getAddress()`

also you can get device name,but maybe it is null.

also fliter it by the rss value is max.

Comment: Using the mac address would only work for that 1 device. I need to be able to recognise a device by "type" and then connect to that.

Answer (score 0):

By examining the scanRecord byte array you could obtain additional information about the device.

An advertisement is very limited in number of bytes you can send out, you could provide more info about your device if you enable active scan. Your scanner obtains then a scan response packet, whichs is just like the normal advertisement packet but with more room in it.